# License info for Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I would like to setup the X-Pack Kerberos authentication (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-overview/7.1/kerberos-realm.html) in my elasticsearch. Is this a free version or a paid version? Will someone guide on where can I get the details?

I am using Elasticsearch version 7.1.0

In this site: https://www.elastic.co/blog/security-for-elasticsearch-is-now-free, it mentioned that its free for security but in this site, https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions, it is gray-out under the basic package. Gray-out means its not supporting for the basic/free version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **Kerberos authentication is not part of the open source/free version.**

It's a bit missleading that they put the SSO features under the section "security". It's correct that starting with version 7.1.0, security became part of the free-to-use version of the Elastic Stack. But this basically concentrates on the TLS encrypted communication, which was not included in versions prior to 7.1.0

Comment: I see. Really grateful for your fast response. Do you know of any kerberos authentication I am able to config with Elasticsearch or even kibana, I am using Kibana to view the data in Elasticsearch and I really need to provide authentication for it.

Comment: You are not able to set up any SSO/authentication without getting a paid subscription.

Comment: apt-get_install_skill: I got it. Thanks for the info